# Remember user selection and either redirect or hide modal box on next visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to create a modal box that prompts visitors to choose between A or B. If user chooses A, they will be redirected to another page, and if B, then they stay on the current website, but the modal box dissapears giving them access to the contents.

I also need an option to "remember me", and if checked, this will remember their profile and if not, they will be prompted again to make a selection betweeen A and B. Here is what I have so far.

The redirection part works, but I cannot get the modal to work.

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window"> Please identity yourself
    <div id="lorem" style="text-align:center">
      <FORM NAME="form1">
        <select onchange="formChanged(this);" NAME="user" SIZE="1">
          <OPTION VALUE="non-value">Please make a selection
          <OPTION VALUE="https://redirection.com">PI
          <OPTION VALUE="fa">FA
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" checked />Remember me
      </FORM>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 1478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

```js
setStatus = document.getElementById('remember');
setStatus.onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('remember', "true");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('remember', "false");
  }
}

getStstus = localStorage.getItem('remember');
if (getStstus == 'true') {
  document.getElementById('remember').checked = true;
}

//  localStorage.clear();
if (localStorage && localStorage.user && remember.checked) {
  location = localStorage.user;
}

function formChanged(form) {
  var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
  if (val !== 'non-value' && val !== 'fa') {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.user = val;
    }
    location = val;
  }

  var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
  if (val == 'fa') {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.user = val;
    }
    $('.window').hide();
    $('#mask').hide();
  }
}
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
    
    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();
          
    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
//$('#mask').click(function () {
//  $(this).hide();
//  $('.window').hide();
//});
```

});

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the modal to work? The window doesn't appear on load?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain. When the user selects B from the drop down menu and checks remember me, on his next visit, the modal box should no longer appear.

Comment: Can you show the part where you show the modal box? You should have a `$('.window').show()` somewhere, probably in your `document.ready()`

Comment: Correct. I have added the JS for the modal window above.

Comment: Can someone please help. I've been stuck on this for days. I have added a fiddle here. 

https://jsfiddle.net/dcistudiosltd/5rmq6gyp/

So basically, what I want is, then you select PI, you get redirected. If you select FA, the modal window goes away and you can access the content, and finally on your next visit, your choice will be remembered and you will either be redirected on given access to the page. Hope this makes sense. –

Comment: The redirection part works, ie, when you select PI it redirects you and remembers on your next visit, and you are automatically redirected. I just can't get the FA part to  dismiss the modal window forever when FA is selected from the drop down. Anyone?